# Removing white-space from a pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, crop, pdfbox

I'm calling Fedex API to generate a shipping label. The API returns a byte array. I then write this byte array to a pdf using:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("xyz.pdf"), imgBytes);  //imgBytes is the response I get from Fedex API
```

However, when I open the file, I see that the actual label occupies only about 2/3rd by width and 1/2 by height of the entire pdf because of which I'm having a lot of white space in the PDF.

Is it possible to somehow remove this white-space using PDFBox? Or is it possible to remove the white-space while saving the byte array to the pdf file?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an example PDF?